# PHP: how detect which file is requiring another file?

Tags: php

I've a .php file that is sending a mail in a client's website.

It's absolutely a caos this websiste, and I'm not able to understand WHERE this script is called from (it's not a class, it'pure php).

Is there a way in PHP to detect which file is calling this one?

i'm doing a find-in-file in the whole site and there is no track of this file. Probably is called due to some mysql config, but, really, I need to find the file that in the end is including this php file.

NOTE: Just to avoid further confusion, I need to obtain these infos at runtime

Comment: Sure. Just rename/delete the file and you will see what file spits errors.

Comment: There's [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) and [`get_included_files()`](http://php.net/get_included_files) you could use.

Comment: Disable the mail function via PHP.ini? If the file was put there maliciously I doubt if simple find/replace would work.

Comment: I would go using a brute force attack to the site: 1. create a sandbox copy of the site for my tests. 2. rename the file and try to see where the site breaks up... or more politely would use notepad++ or komodo to search in the whole directory for that file name :)

Comment: You can use xdebug (http://xdebug.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Linux command line. For example `grep -r` is pretty helpful:

```
grep -r 'a.php' source_folder
```

If you prefer an IDE, use the recursive search function of your IDE.

If the name of the included file is generated at runtime, a simple search would fail. In this case you can use the functions `debug_backtrace()` or `get_included_file()` to get more information.

I won't miss to mention xdebug which can be used to debug the application or produce trace files containing all function calls and parameters, this again can be searched through with.

Comment: sorry, I'm able to do a find in file. I need a way to print_our to video which php file is running the script in object.

Comment: Sure there are situations where `grep` can't help. Like the name is composed of something or comes from a db. (btw, phpmyadmin offers I comfortable search across all tables). Others have suggested `debug_backtrace()`. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes, the way is `debug_backtrace()` and `get_included_file()`, because I need this info at runime